# Aggregating using regex in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have the following cell in my spreadsheet. It is a string that has the structure of a JSON object.

```
D2 = {color: white, quantity: 23, size: small}, {color: black, size: medium, Quantity: 40}
```

For the cell `D3`, I want the output to be 63, which is the total of the quantities found in `D2`. Moreover, the following things should be noted:

- If something goes wrong, for example, if a quantity is given as a string, then `D3` is simply kept empty.
- Anytime `D2` is updated, `D3` is updated as well.
- If `D3` is updated manually, that result is kept instead of the formula. This will happen for rows where `D2` is empty.

Is there any way to do this using Google Sheets? I tried using `REGEXEXTRACT`, however, it did not produce any result. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edits:

- The order of the attributes is not important. For example, the quantity can appear before or after the size.
- The case is also not important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(REGEXREPLACE(SPLIT(D22, ":"), "}.*", "")))
```

[image: 0]

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(REGEXREPLACE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(D21, "quantity:", "♦"), "♦"), "}.*", "")))
```

[image: 0]
[image: 0]

Comment: It does not really focus specifically on "quantity" it seems? If my cell had another attribute called "price", that would also be aggregated, correct?

Comment: @darkhorse yes, correct. answer updated - the second one focuses on quantity only

Comment: Sorry to add a comment after accepting the answer, however, is there some way to make the regex case insensitive? For example, I would want to match "Quantity" as well.

Comment: you either do: `=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(REGEXREPLACE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(D21, "Quantity:|quantity:", "♦"), "♦"), "}.*", "")))` or `=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(REGEXREPLACE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(D21), "quantity:", "♦"), "♦"), "}.*", "")))`

Comment: I have noticed something else. If I add an attribute after the quantity within that JSON object, then that quantity is not aggregated.

Comment: Sure. I updated the original question with some edits. That should make it more clear. In short, you got everything right. However, the order in which the quantity appears should not matter.

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(REGEXREPLACE(SPLIT(
 SUBSTITUTE(D26, "uantity:", "♦"), "♦"), ",.*|}.*", "")))` - https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBsLC.png